# Can we export data from exacttarget to SFDC using Data Export

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Currently my ET and SFDC are connected through v5 connector and I'm able to import salesforce data into ET using import functionality of ET.
Now I want to push data back into SFDC using Data Export.
I want to know how we can do this.
In file transfer we have upload type and In file location I'm able to select Salesforce objects & report.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can only use that feature to import records.

As long as you are updating existing records (and not creating new ones), then I'd suggest you use the [Data Stream feature](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/integrating_data_into_your_account_with_data_stream/). This is similar to Data Import, with a few differences:

1. It only works with Salesforce Objects (not reports)
2. It **synchronizes** records (rather than just importing them)
3. You can set a polling frequency in the synchronization (rather than needing to create an Automation)
4. You can edit the fields to synchronize after creating it (unlike Data Import where you have to start over).

Follow [these instructions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_sources/creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources/) to enable data synchronization. The feature is probably not enabled on your account though. If it's not, simply open a support case and request it to be enabled on your account.

Comment: will it also sync exacttarget data with saleforce. It seems it will only sync sfdc data with exacttarget not vice versa.

Comment: Providing you have an object (or custom object) in SFDC, it will be available for synchronization. However, you need to have an object in SFDC to synchronize in the first place, you can't choose a Data Extension and magically get that to appear as a new object in SFDC.

Comment: Okay that means if I have an object(custom) in salesforce  i can synchronise data extension with that object correct.  Is there any limitation

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but you can only synchronize **updated** records from the Data Extension. That is, you can't create new records in the Data Extension and then expect them to appear in your object. However, any new records that are created in SFDC will be sync'd to the DE.

Comment: Thanks man it is very helpful. One more thing can u please tell me how can I directly update record in exacttarget?

Comment: you can either update a record field in a DE manually (in Contact Builder), or using AMPscript, the Fuel REST or SOAP API. Let me know if you need further direction.

Comment: We don't have contact builder enabled in our account. In DE we don't have update options. I'am not aware about amp script , fuel rest and soap api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38861/discussion-between-salesforce-developer-and-eliot-harper).

Answer (score 1):

You can create and update salesforce records using the following **AMPScript** functions, [CreateSalesforceObject()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/#CreateSalesforceObject) and [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/#UpdateSingleSalesforceObject)

The UpdateSingleSalesforceObject() function does require that you know the ID value on the record first.

reference:  [AMPScript Functions for use with Salesforce.com](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/)